# Erro ao colocar compilação condicional no arquivo AssemblyInfo.cs

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, assembly

Quando coloco isso em meu AssenblyInfo.cs não compila

```
#if DEBUG
[assembly: Application(Debuggable=true)]
#else
[assembly: Application(Debuggable=false)]
#endif
```

e dá erro em quase todas as classes.

> Falha inesperada da tarefa "GenerateJavaStubs".
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Application cannot have both a type
>   with an [Application] attribute and an [assembly:Application]
>   attribute.    em
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ManifestDocument.CreateApplicationElement(XElement
>   manifest, String applicationClass, List`1 subclasses, List`1
>   selectedWhitelistAssemblies)    em
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ManifestDocument.Merge(List`1 subclasses, List`1
>   selectedWhitelistAssemblies, String applicationClass, Boolean embed,
>   String bundledWearApplicationName, IEnumerable`1
>   mergedManifestDocuments)    em
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.GenerateJavaStubs.Run(DirectoryAssemblyResolver
>   res)    em Xamarin.Android.Tasks.GenerateJavaStubs.Execute()    em
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>   em
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext() Autorizador.Android

assim ficou o arquivo AssemblyInfo.cs

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Android.App;
using Xamarin.Forms;

#if DEBUG
[assembly: Application(Debuggable=true)]
#else
[assembly: Application(Debuggable = false)]
#endif

// General Information about an assembly is controlled through the following 
// set of attributes. Change these attribute values to modify the information
// associated with an assembly.
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("Autorizador.Android")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("Autorizador.Android")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright ©  2014")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]
[assembly: ComVisible(false)]

// Version information for an assembly consists of the following four values:
//
//      Major Version
//      Minor Version 
//      Build Number
//      Revision
//
// You can specify all the values or you can default the Build and Revision Numbers 
// by using the '*' as shown below:
// [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]

// Add some common permissions, these can be removed if not needed
[assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.Internet)]
[assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage)]
//[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TabbedPage), typeof(BadgedTabbedPageRenderer))]
```

Necessito habilitar alguma permissão ou não? Fico no aguardo.

Comment: Você inseriu no seu AssemblyInfo e na sua classe esse atributo? O erro esta dizendo que isso não pode ocorrer.

Comment: @GabrielColetta, isso mesmo. Foi mal, deveria ter lido com mais detalhes. O erro é todo meu.